# How to give userchoice file name in browserdialog box

Tags: c#

Hi in my windows form application i want to save some data in a folder and when user selcts the browse button it should browse to reqired folder and should consist of a textbox to enter the filename of user choice. How can i achieve this . The below code is not working for me

```
      private void OutputFolder_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        FolderBrowserDialog fd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        try
        {
            if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(OutputFolder.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Please provide output file to do backup ");
                    return;
                }
                outputFileName = fd.SelectedPath + "\\" + outputFileName;
                File.Create(outputFileName).Dispose();
                OutputFolder.Text = outputFileName;
                //File.Create(outputFileName);
                DisplayMainWindow("Selected path to backup" + outputFileName);
                Logger.Log("Selected path to backup" + outputFileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception" + ex);

    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tah40xd.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx).

The example in the MSDN page should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need the [`SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) class.